# Login and Password Help using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I want to create a simple task of logging into a website using HtmlUnit in Java. From all the content i've searched, usually people have element name's or id to search from. However in my particular case, there is none of that. When i click on the Username/Password field from the website and hit inspect (chrome), this is what I get:

```
<input type="email" class="js-email form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter email">
<input type="password" class="js-password form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter password">

<button type="submit" class="js-login btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 140px" disabled="">
<span class="vs-login-text">Log In</span><i class="vs-spinner fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
</button>
```

The corresponding XPath is:=

```
 //*[@id="login"]/div[3]/form/div[2]/input[2]
```

This is the Java Code I implemented referencing online:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlOption;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSelect;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import java.util.*;
public class V1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("Site address");

    //Trying something here
    final List<?> divs = page.getElementsByTagName("<input>");
    System.out.println("It is: " + x);


    HtmlElement usrname = page.getElementByName("email");
    usrname.click();
    usrname.type("myusername@123.com");

    HtmlElement psswrd = page.getElementByName("password");
    psswrd.click();
    psswrd.type("mypassword");

    HtmlElement signin = page.getElementByName("submit");
    signin.click();
    System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
    webClient.close();;
}
```

The task in hand is simple, however, since I am unable to get the element name/id, the above doesn't work and throws Element not found exception. I tried printing elements by tag (input and ) but that returned a empty [].

Can anyone guide on what changes or additions to make, so I can add the email/password combination and login?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the elements by their `xpath`:

```
HtmlTextInput email = (HtmlTextInput) page.getByXPath("//*[@id='login']/div[3]/form/div[2]/input[2]").get(0);
email.setValueAttribute("email");
HtmlPasswordInput password = (HtmlPasswordInput) page.getByXPath(" //*[@id='login']/div[3]/form/div[2]/input[3]").get(0);
password.setValueAttribute("password");

HtmlButton submitButton = (HtmlButton) page.getByXPath("yourXPath").get(0);
page = submitButton.click();
```

I am not sure that these xpaths are correct, you should recheck them in your page's html.

Comment: I am getting ArrayOutOfBound Error on your first line of code.  Tried for input[0], Tried for input[1], Tried for input[2], Tried for input[3] and same for get(0-2)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding getElementsByTagName()
You have to use the tag name (not the whole tag) e.g.

```
final List<?> divs = page.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Regarding the web page. If you open the page with a real browser you will see a start page that does some js magic. After a while the page will be replaces with the login screen.
You have to do more or less the same with HtmlUnit.

```
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("Site address");
```

Will return the initial page. Usually the javascript starts async. So you have to wait for that to finish. And take care, the javascript might have replaced the page by another one (e.g. doing a redirect). It is a good idea to get the current page by asking the window for that.
Additionally you can use page.asXML() to dump the code of the page you are working with.

Comment: Yes, I tried with "input", "<Input>".. Both don't work

Comment: Is the page public? Can i try that? Which version of HtmlUnit do you use?